# add_rewrite_rule redirects if value = 1

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm currently having a small issue with `add_rewrite_rule` and can't seem to find any similar issues on stack overflow (even though there seems to be a lot).

It works fine for every URL I try:

```
profile/0/

profile/2/

profile/12313131/
```

I'm able to get the variable easy enough using `$wp_query->query_vars['pid']`

But if I try:

```
profile/1/
```

it always redirects to `profile/`

This is the only value that won't work. I can work around this if need be but wondering why this is the case? This is the first time I've had to use `add_rewrite_rule` and I normally just use `htaccess`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code I'm using is:

```
function profile_rewrite() {

    add_rewrite_tag('%pid%', '([0-9]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^profile/([0-9]+)/?', 'profile/?pid=$1', 'top');

}
add_action( 'init', 'profile_rewrite', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: This sounds like the pagination behavior kicking in. WordPress doesn't let you go to page 1 of a paginated page/archive, it redirects to the root page- page numbers start at 2. Your URL pattern is identical to the pagination rule for a single page.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: But you should be OK, because you add your rewrite rule on top, so it has higher priority. Do you have a page with slug “profile”? How do you process requests that match your rewrite rule?

Comment: I'm creating a small user plugin. At present, I created a page with the slug profile, where I put some shortcode on it to display either current users profile with editing options or another users profile. So the requests are processed through a class in the plugin. I managed to create a small workaround by hooking into `redirect_canonical` and stopping the redirect for that page only. That allowed me to enter a value of 1 and not be redirected so I suspect @Milo was correct.